# Having issues using a class within a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Trying to get an 'edit' VC to pass back to a 'display' VC the new information that's been updated by the User via Storyboard segue but having difficulty storing the user inputs into my initialized class 'Event'

I keep getting this error

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Event' with an argument list of type '(eventName: String, eventLocation: String, eventStart: String, eventDescription: String, eventHost: String)'
```

My edit (source) VC (error in the prepare for...)

```
class EditEventDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eventStartDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eventLocation: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eventDescription: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var eventHost: UITextField!

var event:Event?
var eventUpdate:Event?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //imageView.image = detail?.photo
    eventName.text = event?.eventName
    eventStartDate.text = event?.eventStart
    eventLocation.text = event?.eventLocation
    eventDescription.text = event?.eventDescription
    eventHost.text = event?.eventHost

    guard let urlString = (event?.eventCoverUrl) else { return  }
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
         guard url != nil else {
             //Couldn't create url object
             return
         }
    self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


   if let eventName = eventName.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
       let eventStart = eventStartDate.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
       let eventLocation = eventLocation.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
       let eventDescription = eventDescription.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
       let eventHost = eventHost.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
    self.event = Event(eventName: eventName, eventLocation: eventLocation, eventStart: eventStart, eventDescription: eventDescription, eventHost: eventHost)
   }}}
```

Here's my class

```
class Event {

var adminUser:String?
var eventCreated:Date?
var eventId:String?
var eventName:String?
var eventCoverUrl:String?
var eventLocation:String?
var eventStart:String?
var eventEnd:Date?
var eventStatus:String?
//var eventParticipants: [String?]
var eventDescription:String?
var eventDeleteDate:Date?
var eventHost:String?


init?(snapshot:DocumentSnapshot){

    self.eventId = snapshot.get("eventId") as? String ?? "No event Id"
    self.adminUser = snapshot.get("adminUser") as? String ?? "No admin user"
    //self.eventCreated = snapshot.get("eventCreated") as? Date ?? "No Event Created Date"
    self.eventName = snapshot.get("eventName") as? String ?? "No Event Name"
    self.eventCoverUrl = snapshot.get("eventCoverUrl") as? String ?? "No Cover URL"
    self.eventLocation = snapshot.get("eventLocation") as? String ?? "No Location"
    self.eventStart = snapshot.get("eventStart") as? String ?? "No Start Date"
    self.eventDescription = snapshot.get("eventDescription") as? String ?? "No Event Description"
    self.eventHost = snapshot.get("eventHost") as? String ?? "No Event Host"
    self.eventStatus = snapshot.get("eventStatus") as? String ?? "No Event Status"

}

init(adminUser:String?, eventId:String?, eventName:String?, eventCoverUrl:String?, eventLocation:String?, eventStart:String?, eventStatus:String?, eventDescription:String?, eventHost:String?) {

    self.adminUser = adminUser ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventId = eventId ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventName = eventName ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventCoverUrl = eventCoverUrl ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventLocation = eventLocation ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventStart = eventStart ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventStatus = eventStatus ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventDescription = eventDescription ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
    self.eventHost = eventHost ?? "No \(LocalizedError.self)"
}
}
```

I've tried numerous ways but nothing lets me take the user input for edited fields to create an 'event' and later pass it into my display (destination) VC via unwind segue that's already working.

This is the updated code of the Event class with updated params initialized to a blank string.  All else remains as it is above.

```
var adminUser = ""
var eventCreated = ""
var eventId = ""
var eventName = ""
var eventCoverUrl = ""
var eventLocation = ""
var eventStart = ""
var eventEnd:Date?
var eventStatus:String?
//var eventParticipants: [String?]
var eventDescription = ""
var eventDeleteDate = ""
var eventHost = ""
```

Comment: Your formal parameters `init(adminUser:String?, eventId:String?, eventName:String?, eventCoverUrl:String?, eventLocation:String?, eventStart:String?, eventStatus:String?, eventDescription:String?, eventHost:String?) {` doesn't match the parameters you're trying to use `(eventName: String, eventLocation: String, eventStart: String, eventDescription: String, eventHost: String)`.  You can't skip parameters unless they have default values (specified in the formal parameter list)

Comment: where is the `Event(eventName, eventLocation, eventStart, eventDescription, eventHost)` method?  You never defined it.  You can't just not include parameters.

Comment: Since I'm a n00b here, can you help me understand more basically?  If I initialize adminUser, eventId, eventName, eventCoverUrl.... to param = " " i still get the same error.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to create the 'event' object rather than using a predefined intilizer in that only the fields that have been updated via user typing something into the respective text field will need to be passed via the segue?

Comment: @akash23a Post code where you initialized them all to a blank string.  That should be your solution.

Comment: @SamuelNoyes in the last code snippet up above with the Event class params initialized to blank strings.  If I should recopy the entire new class please let me know

Comment: @akash23a You still need to include them in the function call.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't leave parameters out of a function call.  The `Event(eventName, eventLocation, eventStart, eventDescription, eventHost)` is undefined because the actual method is `Event(adminUser, eventId, eventName, eventCoverUrl, eventLocation, eventStart, eventStatus, eventDescription, eventHost)` You need to change the last line in prepareForSegue to:

```
self.event = Event(adminUser: adminUser, eventId: eventId, eventName: eventName, eventCoverUrl: eventCoverUrl, eventLocation: eventLocation, eventStart: eventStart, eventStatus:eventStatus, eventDescription: eventDescription, eventHost: eventHost)
```

Comment: so for instance adminUser isn't a field on this VC, what would go to the right of adminUser: ? since every param needs to be present on this function call.  Obviously eventName: eventName, and so on for the params that are actually on this VC.

Comment: Well you already have handlers in case any of the arguments are nil, so simply put `adminUser: nil`.  Or create another initializer without the adminUser argument.